# Logical Error in building a compiler with java

Tags: java

I am currently building a very small compiler for a very simple java dependent language. the source code of my project is as follows:

class twind:

```
import parse.parseFrom;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class twind
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        parseFrom pF=new parseFrom();
        String[] typed=new String[20];
        int lim=0;
        System.out.println("test1:");
        for(int i=0;i<typed.length;i++)
        {
            typed[i]=in.nextLine();
            if(typed[i].equals("finish"))
            {
                lim=i;
                break;
            }

        }
        for(int i=0;i<lim;i++)
        {
            pF.line(typed[i]);
        }
   }
```

}

package parse:

class parseFrom:

```
 package parse;
 public class parseFrom
 {
     private String command;
     private String line;
     public void line(String line)
     {
         System.out.print("\f");
         int U_B=line.indexOf(' ');
         int L_B=0;
         this.line=line;
         command=line.substring(L_B,U_B);
         String SEND_TO=command;
         recognize(SEND_TO);
     } 

     public void recognize(String command)
     {
         String[] list=
         {
             "print","printLine","finish"
         };
         for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
         {
              if(command.equals(list[i]))
              {
                  perform(list[i]);
              }
         }
      }

  public void perform(String command)
  {
       if(command.equals("print"))
       {
           print(this.line);
       }
       if(command.equals("printLine"))
       {
           printLine(this.line);
       }
       if(command.equals("finish"))
       {
           // my code is't yet finished, apologies
       }
  }
  public void print(String line)
  {
       System.out.print(line.substring(line.indexOf(' ')+1));

  }
  public void printLine(String line)
  {
       System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf(' ')+1));
  }
 }
```

when we type in the commands as follows in the terminal window/console:

```
  printLine hello
  printLine world
  finish
```

the output should be

```
  hello 
  world
```

but is actually:

```
  world
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: I don't think it'll even print 'world'. Are you sure you've pasted right code here?

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Your code outputs  `hello world` for me.

Comment: Same, the code outputs hello world. Maybe you're putting the commands on the same line?

Comment: maybe the case you adding some spaces add the start or something so you can try `trim()`

Comment: Got it. It was the \f sequence at the class parseFrom. Silly me.